# I need to do a mass find and replace ¿May I do it with a table of "subtitutions"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

I have a main table with patients and hospitals. The hospitals have typo errors and some of them are without an article, like following.

```
Name       Hospital
----------------------------
Fulano     Hospital Princesa
Mengano    Princesa
Futano     La PRincesa
Octano     Paz
Nonano     La Paz
Zipi       PAz
```

I need to change all "Princesa" cells to "Hospital La Princesa" and all "La Paz" cells to "Hospital La Paz".

Each time I correct the database, I manually do a "find and replace" ("*inc*" -> "Hospital La Princesa", and "*az*" -> "Hospital La Paz")

Because there are so many hospitals (near 15) and so many rows in the main table, I want to know if there is a easy way to do this (maybe with a vlookup, maybe with VBA)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FixHospitalNames()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, itm As Variant, i As Long
    Dim hOld As Variant, hNew As Variant, extras As Variant

    extras = Split("hospital,la, ", ",") 'removes any extras (splits string by ",")

    hOld = Split("princesa paz")         'replace these 2 items with the 2 items from hNew
    hNew = Split("Hospital La Princesa,Hospital La Paz", ",")

    With Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2).Offset(1)  'Update Sheet and Column as needed

        For Each itm In extras
            .Replace What:=itm, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next

        For i = 0 To UBound(hOld)
            .Replace What:=hOld(i), Replacement:=hNew(i), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

---

Comment: Thanks very much!! Is it possible to do with wilcards (*rinc* -> Hospital la Princesa; *az* -> Hospital La Paz)??

Comment: Yes @NicolasRiera simply code it in yourself. Your question didn't ask for wild cards and you haven't up voted or marked as an answer (and if you don't have enough rep I suggest you try to answer other questions as the community works well when people give back). :)

Comment: Ok @Dave, but may I change the code to add "**rin**" instead "princesa"?

`hOld = Split("rin az") 
    hNew = Split("Hospital La Princesa,Hospital La Paz", ",")`